# R fill missing dates by category

Tags: r, tidyr

```
x<-data.frame(product=c(rep("A",3),rep("B",4)),
          xdate=as.Date(c("2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-04",'2020-01-02','2020-01-04','2020-01-07','2020-01-08')),
          number=sample(1:10,7))
```

In sample data I want to fill missing dates by category. In the sample data it means that
for category A I want all missing dates between it's minimum date 2020-01-01 and maximum '2020-01-04
and the same logic for category B. I am aware of function complete but it seems like it's insufficient for what I am looking for. And the number variable should be filled with 0s

Comment: Hello tomas hujo, there is no missing date in your example. What do you mean by "I want all missing dates between it's minimum date 2020-01-01 and maximum '2020-01-04 ..." which variable is to be filled ? with 0 ?

Comment: If you could give an example of result wanted, that would help.

Comment: Hi I meant implicitly missing like 2020-01-03 for category A. but the anwer below solves it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `complete` here as well :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x %>%
  group_by(product) %>%
  complete(xdate = seq(min(xdate), max(xdate), by = "1 day"), fill = list(number = 0))
```

Comment: ouu group by :))